How to customize the error message returned when model binding fails due to a JSON deserialization exception?
I have a security problem in my app. When somebody sends wrong json to my endpoint (for example, pass type string instead if int), my API displays json deserialisation exception:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "$.questions[0].answers": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to TestingService.Business.Features.V1.Test.Models.Answer[]. Path: $.questions[0].answers | LineNumber: 11 | BytePositionInLine: 20."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-690e01e0fb451eed8afa4530616fa13f-0396f3a592bd1518-00"
}

When I try to handle it using IExceptionFilter, I can not do this, because the exception is thrown before this pipeline was reached.
When I use middleware - I can't catch this exception either.
My controller setup:
services.AddControllers(options =>
                options.Filters.Add(new ApiErrorFilter()))
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new Core.Infrastructure.DateTimeConverter());
            });

How to handle this exception and replace it with a custom one?

@dbc Yes, you right. It appears when I receive an incoming request. I edited question.

@DarkBee - I thought the title was clearer before your edit, as it indicated that the question isn't about handling exceptions when the serializer is called directly.

Should questions include "tags" in their titles?

It's not a tag like C# - how to handle exception... it's an integral part of the statement of the question, because it indicates the problem arises during the processing pipeline rather than from some direct call to the serializer.  We'll have to agree to disagree on this one, or we can take it to meta.

@JamesBondCaesar - not sure these answer your question, but I found How do I customize ASP.Net Core model binding errors? and ASP.NET Core customize the error when model binding fails but also an open github issue Model binding failure should return friendlier message with option to customize it #12472.  Do any of those help?

That's not an exception, it's the default response of model binding error (which returns 400 Bad Request). You can customize it with ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions.

@Parsa99 Can you give me an example, how to configure it ? I need to replace response model to my own with my own text.

Thanks for @Parsa99 - he suggested the answer. For anyone who will try to find in in the future, I will post here an example that I was found in the internet.


services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add<ApiErrorFilter>();
            })
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(opt=>
            {
                opt.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = false;
                opt.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context=>{
                
                    bool knownExceptions = context.ModelState.Values
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                    .Where(x => x.Exception is JsonException || (x.Exception is null && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ErrorMessage) == false)).Count() > 0;
                    if (knownExceptions)
                    {
                        var error = new ProblemDetails
                        {
                            Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                            Title = "Test",
                        };

                            return new ObjectResult(error)
                        {
                            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity,
                        }; //new BadRequestResult(new { state = false, message = "InvalidParameterError" });
                    }
                // ...
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
                };
            })
            .AddJsonOptions(DefaultJsonOptions.OptionsConfiguration);



